# PureScript UI Library for production

Tags: purescript

There are several UI libraries for the PureScript, such as purescript-thermite, purescript-halogen, purescript-react-simple and other. Which library is right for the production?

Comment: Library recommendations are off-topic on stackoverflow, try something like the purescript subreddit for discussion-like questions like this.

Comment: It's fairly new, but you might also consider purescript-concur (https://github.com/ajnsit/purescript-concur). It's currently based on react (with other backends in progress), and its primary goal is ease of use. It allows you to incrementally build your UI. You can see some demos here - https://ajnsit.github.io/purescript-concur/, and the example sources here - https://github.com/ajnsit/purescript-concur/tree/master/examples/Test.

Comment: I would suggest you to use framework called Presto which is to develop UI for android, IOS and web.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have written a fairly large production application using Halogen and very happy with the developer experience, the documentation, libraries available (like routing and ajax specifically for Halogen) and support from the developers of Halogen.

Halogen is used by Slamdata for their main application and they have a few full-time developers on it that are also quick to answers questions on IRC or Slack. This gives some assurance that Halogen will be kept maintained where it is my impression that the other options only have a single main developer.

Size of js bundle tends to be smaller with Halogen than with the other options, because Halogen does not rely on React.

Comment: Mikkel - where is their IRC chan? I'd love to pop in.

Comment: #purescript on freenode. Not too active though.